# How to Mock a Google API Library with Python 3.7 for Unit Testing

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, google-app-engine, mocking, google-client

I'm trying to create a set of Unit Tests to test the Google Client Library for Bigquery. I'm struggling to make a Unittest file which will mock the client and will let me test my inputs. I've provided a simple script with some set functionality to return a list of Tables that belong to the DataSet.

Would somebody show me a sample example of mocking the Google Client Library as the documentation I have found @ https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/tests/unit/test_client.py is not directly interacting with the methods of the code, so I am unable to apply it to my code.

Appreciate any ideas or ways to achieve this, I can't seem to find anywhere on Stack Overflow documenting this problem.

Thanks

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery


def get_dataset():
    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('some_client_secret.json')

    dataset_id = 'some_project.some_dataset'

    dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_id)

    full_dataset_id = "{}.{}".format(dataset.project, dataset.dataset_id)
    friendly_name = dataset.friendly_name
    print(
        "Got dataset '{}' with friendly_name '{}'.".format(
            full_dataset_id, friendly_name
        )
    )

    # View dataset properties
    print("Description: {}".format(dataset.description))
    print("Labels:")
    labels = dataset.labels
    if labels:
        for label, value in labels.items():
            print("\t{}: {}".format(label, value))
    else:
        print("\tDataset has no labels defined.")

    # View tables in dataset
    print("Tables:")
    tables = list(client.list_tables(dataset))  # API request(s)
    if tables:
        for table in tables:
            print("\t{}".format(table.table_id))
    else:
        print("\tThis dataset does not contain any tables.")
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It took a fair amount of Googling, and trial and error, to figure out how to do this, and I just got it working, so I thought it was worth sharing.

`unittest` provides `patch` which allows you to mock a function **at the point of use**, ie. replace a Google API call in your code under test, and `mock`, which allows you to further customise the result of accessing attributes and calling functions on that mock.

The `unittest` docs explaining patching here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

This does explain how it works, but the best explanation I found in order to understand how to do this properly is:
http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/

Here is a Python script to be tested,  `mocking_google.py`, containing references to Google Storage and BigQuery APIs:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client as bigqueryClient
from google.cloud.storage import Client as storageClient

def list_blobs():

    storage_client = storageClient(project='test')

    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs('bucket', prefix='prefix')

    return blobs

def extract_table():

    bigquery_client = bigqueryClient(project='test')

    job = bigquery_client.extract_table('project.dataset.table_id', destination_uris='uri')

    return job
```

Here is the unit test:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

from src.data.mocking_google import list_blobs, extract_table

@pytest.fixture
def extract_result():
    'Mock extract_job result with properties needed'
    er = Mock()
    er.return_value = 1
    return er

@pytest.fixture
def extract_job(extract_result):
    'Mock extract_job with properties needed'
    ej = Mock()
    ej.job_id = 1
    ej.result.return_value = 2
    return ej

@patch("src.data.mocking_google.storageClient")
def test_list_blobs(storageClient):

    storageClient().list_blobs.return_value = [1,2]

    blob_list = list_blobs()

    storageClient().list_blobs.assert_called_with('bucket', prefix='prefix')
    assert blob_list == [1,2]

@patch("src.data.mocking_google.bigqueryClient")
def test_extract_table(bigqueryClient,extract_job):

    bigqueryClient().extract_table.return_value = extract_job

    job = extract_table()

    bigqueryClient().extract_table.assert_called_with('project.dataset.table_id', destination_uris='uri')
    assert job.job_id == 1
    assert job.result() == 2
```

Here is the test results:

```
pytest -v src/tests/data/test_mocking_google.py============================================================ test session starts =============================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.6, pytest-5.3.5, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /Users/gaya/.local/share/virtualenvs/autoencoder-recommendation-copy-zpYZ6J1x/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/gaya/Documents/GitHub/mlops-autoencoder-recommendation, inifile: tox.ini
plugins: cov-2.8.1
collected 2 items                                                                                                                            

src/tests/data/test_mocking_google.py::test_list_blobs PASSED                                                                          [ 50%]
src/tests/data/test_mocking_google.py::test_extract_table PASSED                                                                       [100%]

============================================================= 2 passed in 1.14s ==============================================================
```

Happy to explain further if how this works is not clear :)

Comment: Do you need valid credentials to run the test?

Comment: as long as you're mocking the Google API client, like ```storageClient``` or ```bigqueryClient``` in my example, then no, because it never tries to open a connection to Google

Comment: What a great answer! Thanks for sharing jut seen this from a bump email apologies! The explaination is great thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to mock bigquery_client if initialized in the main scope, right after the imports?

Comment: @dinigo yes, patching patches the code, not instances

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman can you explain why `extract_job` needs `extract_result`? and what happens when the test runs and the fixtures kick in?

Comment: @cryanbhu fixtures are created before any test runs. They can be used to mock a single function, a class with many methods, dataclasses, etc. ```extract_job``` illustrates how to mock a job 'object' which has both a ```job_id``` attribute and a ```result``` method with a ```return_value```. As you astutely noticed, I probably intended ```extract_result``` to demonstrate using a mocked object within a mocked object and return than mocked object as ```extract_job```s ```result``` return value... but didn't :)

Answer (score 7):

I also find it hard to get around the authentication part and only mock interacting with methods, so I ended up just mocked the whole library. :facepalm:

```py
import sys

from unittest.mock import MagicMock

sys.modules["google.cloud.storage"] = MagicMock()

from your_application import make_app


def test_make_app():
    make_app()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer,  it's a right pain however I have had greater success with patching and mocking parts of my code.