# Can not monkeypatch imported module

Tags: python, unit-testing, monkeypatching

I have a very simple [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage?hl=bg#object_finalize) written in Python and it makes a reference to Google's Secret manager via their Python library.

The code is very simple and it looks like this:

```
import os
from google.cloud import secretmanager
import logging

client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
secret_name = "my-secret"
project_id = os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT')
resource_name = "projects/{}/secrets/{}/versions/latest".format(project_id, secret_name)
response = client.access_secret_version(resource_name)
secret_string = response.payload.data.decode('UTF-8')

def new_measures_handler(data, context):
    logging.info(secret_string)
    print('File: {}.'.format(data['name']))
```

and then I have my simple unit test which is trying to take advantage of [monkey patching](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html):

```
import main

def test_print(capsys, monkeypatch):
    # arrange
    monkeypatch.setenv("GCP_PROJECT", "TestingUser")
    monkeypatch.setattr(secretmanager, "SecretManagerServiceClient", lambda: 1)

    name = 'test'
    data = {'name': name}

    # act
    main.new_measures_handler(data, None)
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()

    #assert
    assert out == 'File: {}.\n'.format(name)
```

Everything goes well with the mock for the environment variable but I can not mock `secretmanager`. It keeps on trying to call the actual API. My ultimate goal is to mock `secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()` and make it return an object which later on can be used by: `client.access_secret_version(resource_name)` (which I will need to mock as well, I think)

Comment: Try: `monkeypatch.setattr(main.secretmanager, "SecretManagerServiceClient", lambda: 1)`. It has to be done this way because you import `secretmanager` into the namespace of `main`.

Comment: @jordanm I tried that but it keeps on failing with the same error. Tries to call the actual API.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. It's because you are calling `SecretManagerServiceClient()` in the top level scope. This means the object is created when `import main` is executed, which is before your monkeypatch. Use `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: @jordanm So, your suggestion is to have `if __name__ == '__main__'` above the function declaration and put the object initializations (`client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()` etc.) inside of it?

Comment: Yes, everything that's above the function definition and below the imports should go in that conditional block.

Comment: I am quite new to Python and I was wondering if it is a good practice to keep the function definition itself also inside the conditional block or not? Btw, you can add an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: And I have noticed that if I leave it like that (only the the part between function definition and imports to be inside the conditional statement) in my test I am getting `NameError: global name 'client' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this question for a working example of using `unittest` patching and mocking to mock Google API calls and return mock results:
[How to Mock a Google API Library with Python 3.7 for Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808461/how-to-mock-a-google-api-library-with-python-3-7-for-unit-testing/60753710#60753710)